# UK visa expiration date

Tags: visas, uk

What exactly does the UK visa expiration date mean? Can I remain in the UK beyond the expiration date of my visa provided I enter before the date of expiration and stay for less than 6 months?

Comment: What kind of visa and for which purposes? For visitors you must leave on or before the expiry date unless you apply for an extension

Answer (score 1):

UK visas are issued with a 'valid until' date. That is the date beyond which you do not have permission to be in the UK. You may enter the UK on the date the validity starts, or at any time after that before the expiry date..

Comment: You overstay from the day your leave to enter or remain becomes invalid, although no automatic reentry ban is applied if it's less than 30 days.

Comment: @xngtng "If you’ve stayed longer than you're allowed to under your visa or leave, this is called overstaying. You'll have 30 days to leave the country from the date it expired."  UK Citizen's Advice Bureau. "If your visa has expired, you have 30 days to leave the UK voluntarily at your own expense before you face a ban on re-entry." - "If you remain in the UK after your visa or Home Office permission has expired, you **may** be considered an overstayer." Lawyer website.

Comment: "The Home Office **may** consider an immigrant to be an “overstayer” if their UK immigration status has expired and they remain in the UK without reasonable cause. You will have 30 days to leave the UK voluntarily at your own expense from when your visa expires." - other UK law site.

Comment: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/823299/applications-from-overstayers-v8.0.pdf The overstay can be disregarded under very limited circumstances (informing the Home Office before expiry or within 14 days etc., so you "may" be not considered overstayer if you have good reasons or exercising a legal appeal right), but the automatic grace period no longer exists. 30 days only matter for automatic overstay reentry bans; overstays of less than 30 days can still be held against the applicant for future applications though.